# When I try to echo my header code, the php code to do so is rendered as plain text

Tags: php

The PHP code at the top of my view page is as follows:

```
<?php
echo $this->view('includes/header');
?>
```

$this->view(); is a function inside my main Controller class. The Home controller class that is rendering the view extends that controller class.

Main Controller Class:

```
<?php

/*
 * main controller class
 */

class Controller
{

    public function view($view, $data = array())
    {
        extract($data);
        // code...

        if(file_exists("../private/views/". $view . ".view.php"))
        {
            return file_get_contents("../private/views/". $view . ".view.php");
        } else {
            return file_get_contents("../private/views/404.view.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Home Controller Class:

```
<?php 

/**
 * home controller
 */
class Home extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // code...
        echo $this->view('home');
    }
}
```

When I view my page, all I see is:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uTpX.png]

Instead of seeing my page with the header files.

Thanks in advance for any help!
Sorry for anything I don't understand. I am relatively new to PHP and MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do in your view method is `return require "paths/there"` . If you return the result of `file_get_content()`, you get the file as plaintext, so it isn't parsed as a php file. You may want to use `require`, `require_once`, `include` or `include_once` following your needs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the reply. I'll try this right now and let you know if it works.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much. I probably would've never thought of that; seems to have fixed it! Once again, thanks!

Comment: Np! You may want to take a look at buffer functions like ob_start and ob_get_clean depending on what you need to do. They can be really useful.

Comment: Alright. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the block of code below is called after initialization of class with method view()?

```
<?php
echo $this->view('includes/header');
?>
```

It seems $this doesn't have any methods.

Comment: My thinking was that $this-> is going to the Home class because that's where the code is being put into. But maybe that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**So the problem of your code is here:**

```
require_once('*Your controller url file*');
$Controller = new Controller();

echo $Controller->view('includes/header');
```

This mode you search to the *controller* file and instantiate the object.

Functions is functionally, but export of the *controller* is wrong.